# how to update private packages with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have a private repository (A) on github that I use as package in other repository (B).
The private package is installed using `pip install git+https`.

How can I update this package on the virtual environment of B?
For example, if a college makes a commit to the main I want to be able to update my virtual environment using something like a pip update.

Pip update doesn't do anything.

The only way I found is uninstalling and installing again the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it using the `--editable` option:

```
$ pip install -e /pat/to/python/package
```

In this way all changes to package in repository A will be immediately reflected in the virtual environment of B.

Comment: But, if I don't wan't to have repo A cloned on my computer, how would I do that? If a college aplies a commit to the repo A I want to be able to update my local environment of repo B using something like a pip update.

Comment: They should release a new version of the package and you install that new version. Otherwise the only solution I am aware of is the one I already suggested: clone repo A locally and install it in virtual environment B using the `--editable` option, then use `git pull` to update your local package.